# iphone objective C colors

Tags: iphone, colors

I have a table view and I would like the cells to be of alternate colors so I have found this code :

```
if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0)
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greyColor];
else
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

it compiles all right but when I run the app I get the following error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UIColor greyColor]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xfbad60'`

well I usually program in android so I thought some colors were defined by default but it seems that's not the case. I am really new to this how could I define some colors something like color black="000000"? Is there a tutorial about this? I have looked around but couldn't find anything.

thks

Comment: i think it is [UIColor grayColor] ;-) just a typo?

Comment: Unfortunately, everything in the programming world is written with American spellings. Color, instead of colour. Gray instead of grey.

Comment: It's really not that hard to go to the definition of these colors in UIColor, to see what's available.

Comment: is it possible to define your custom colors?

Comment: If you want a custom colo(u)r, check out the [UIColor class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - something like `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` should be ideal for your requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use GRAY !

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Comment: thks how about if I want some custom gray? how could i define it?

Comment: You can create your custom colors by playing around with the `RGB Values` and `alpha`

Answer (score 1):

Apple has chosen to use gray over grey:

```
if ((indexPath.row % 2) == 0)
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
else
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```